# About speed improvement when issuing queries with Bigquery from Python

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using Bigquery for a database in my current project. I'm building an API server and would like to improve the API response.

Below I have written my code and execution log.
Although it is a very simple SQL to get the current time, it takes about 1 seconds to execute.
Is there any way to improve this speed?

Code

```
query = f"""
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as current_time
"""

bigquery_client = get_bigquery_client()

end_time = datetime.now()
execution_time = end_time - start_time

print(f"bigquery_client execution_time: {execution_time.total_seconds()}")

query_job = bigquery_client.query(query)

end_time = datetime.now()
execution_time = end_time - start_time

print(f"query_job execution_time: {execution_time.total_seconds()}")


query_results = query_job.result()

end_time = datetime.now()
execution_time = end_time - start_time

print(f"query_results execution_time: {execution_time.total_seconds()}")
```

Log

```
bigquery_client execution_time: 0.049895
query_job execution_time: 0.726436
query_results execution_time: 1.083496
```

Comment: BigQuery is a great tool for query large historical data. Request time of 2 seconds to several minutes are fine. For webpages, only small amount of data is needed to be quered and a fast processing time is important. Please have a look an firebase storage or the real time database. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database

Comment: As Samuel says, bigquery not really meant to be RealTIME database, at my company we used Elastic Search or Redis. Of course there are many other good ones.
So the idea is to use a series of BigQuery jobs to process data and model it into 1 or few final tables. Usually this step is done once a day to process new data. Then load those tables into real-time db that will be called by your Server.